# Ajax - Create tag with custom ID programatically

Tags: ajax, tags, jquery

I'm trying to create an jQuery/Ajax script to import data from a Wordpress API service and want to import the WP tags into my database.

Everything works as expected when I loop through the data and send it to `/actions/tags/createTag` but I'd like to keep the original tag IDs in order to be able to import the posts later and keep the relationship with their tags (Craft automatically assigns a *length+1* ID to new tags).

Any way I can do this?

Comment: Crafts shares all ids for elements so when you create an entry it starts with id 1, when you create a category it has id 2, your tag has id 3 and so on. You won't be able to keep your ids because of that. I would suggest you to save the old/new ids and map them into an array. I could explain you how if you want

Comment: @RobinSchambach That would be great! Thanks

Comment: Do you use Craft 2 or Craft 3?

Comment: Right now I'm using Craft-2.6.2991

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to create a new table/record to store the data

```
class IdRecord extends BaseRecord
{
    /**
     * Returns the name of the database table the model is associated with (sans table prefix). By convention,
     * tables created by plugins should be prefixed with the plugin name and an underscore.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTableName()
    {
        return 'ids';
    }

    /**
     * Returns an array of attributes which map back to columns in the database table.
     *
     * @access protected
     * @return array
     */
    protected function defineAttributes()
    {
        return array(
            'oldId'   => AttributeType::Number,
            'newId' => AttributeType::Number
        );
    }
}
```

Create a new Controller and store with the record

```
public function actionCreateTag()
{
    $this->requireLogin();
    $this->requireAjaxRequest();

    $tag = new TagModel();
    $tag->groupId = craft()->request->getRequiredPost('groupId');
    $tag->getContent()->title = trim(craft()->request->getRequiredPost('title'));
    $oldId = craft()->request->getRequiredPost('oldId');

    if (craft()->tags->saveTag($tag))
    {

        $tagMap = new IdRecord();
        $tagMap->oldId = $oldId;
        $tagMap->newId =  $tag->id;
        $tagMap->save();
        $this->returnJson(array(
            'success' => true,
            'id'      => $tag->id
        ));
    }
    else
    {
        $this->returnJson(array(
            'success' => false
        ));
    }
}
```

And when you are saving your entries you'll do

```
$entry = new EntryModel();
// ... set your content
$oldId = 'number of your old WP tag id';
$tag = IdRecord::model()->find('oldId = :oldId',[
    'oldId' => $oldId
]);
$entry->getContent()->setAttribute('yourTagFieldHandle', $tag->newId);
```

You can use [pluginfactory.io](http://pluginfactory.io) to create your boilerplate.

#### Edit

Another approach. If you receive the title of the tags as an array like `['tag1', 'tag2', 'tag3']` would be something like

```
$ids = [];
foreach($tagTitles as $tagTitle){
    $criteria = craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::Tag);
    $criteria->title = 'your Tag Title';
    $tag = $criteria->first();
    if($tag){
        $ids[] = $tag->id;
    }
}
$entry->getContent()->setAttribute('yourFieldHandle', $ids);
```